# Lua, Love2D, why i'm getting an error on GameObject?

Tags: lua, cs50, game-development

im doing the CS50 game development course and after creating the key and locked block required when i get close to the locked block i get an error saying GameObject.lua 28: attempted to perform arithmetic on field 'y' (nil value)

here is my code for level maker

```
    LevelMaker = Class{}

keyCollected = false

function LevelMaker.generate(width, height)
    local tiles = {}
    local entities = {}
    local objects = {}

    local tileID = TILE_ID_GROUND
    
    -- whether we should draw our tiles with toppers
    local topper = true
    local tileset = math.random(20)
    local topperset = math.random(20)

    -- insert blank tables into tiles for later access
    for x = 1, height do
        table.insert(tiles, {})
    end

    --generate one locked box and one locked key in a random position position 
    local lockBoxPosition = math.random(1, width)
    local keyPosition = math.random(1, width)
    local keyColor = math.random(1, 4) --for reference for the color skin used

    -- column by column generation instead of row; sometimes better for platformers
    for x = 1, width do
        local tileID = TILE_ID_EMPTY
        
        -- lay out the empty space
        for y = 1, 6 do
            table.insert(tiles[y],
                Tile(x, y, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset))
        end

        -- chance to just be emptiness (to be sure to not generate a key and locked box above a chasm)
        if math.random(7) == 1 and x ~= 1 and lockBoxPosition ~= x and keyPosition ~= x then
            for y = 7, height do
                table.insert(tiles[y],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset))
            end
        else
            tileID = TILE_ID_GROUND

            -- height at which we would spawn a potential jump block
            local blockHeight = 4

            for y = 7, height do
                table.insert(tiles[y],
                    Tile(x, y, tileID, y == 7 and topper or nil, tileset, topperset))
            end

            -- chance to generate a pillar
            if math.random(8) == 1 then
                blockHeight = 2
                
                -- chance to generate bush on pillar
                if math.random(8) == 1 then
                    table.insert(objects,
                        GameObject {
                            texture = 'bushes',
                            x = (x - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                            y = (4 - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                            width = 16,
                            height = 16,
                            
                            -- select random frame from bush_ids whitelist, then random row for variance
                            frame = BUSH_IDS[math.random(#BUSH_IDS)] + (math.random(4) - 1) * 7,
                            collidable = false
                        }
                    )
                end
                
                -- pillar tiles
                tiles[5][x] = Tile(x, 5, tileID, topper, tileset, topperset)
                tiles[6][x] = Tile(x, 6, tileID, nil, tileset, topperset)
                tiles[7][x].topper = nil
            
            -- chance to generate bushes
            elseif math.random(8) == 1 and keyPosition ~= x then
                table.insert(objects,
                    GameObject {
                        texture = 'bushes',
                        x = (x - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                        y = (6 - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                        width = 16,
                        height = 16,
                        frame = BUSH_IDS[math.random(#BUSH_IDS)] + (math.random(4) - 1) * 7,
                        collidable = false
                    }
                )
            end

            --spawn the key
            if x == keyPosition then
                table.insert(objects,
                GameObject {
                    texture = 'key-lock',
                    x = (x - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                    y = (blockHeight+1) * TILE_SIZE,
                    width = 16,
                    height = 16,
                    frame = keyColor,
                    collidable = true,
                    consumable = true,
                    solid = false,
                    
                    --key has its own function to add to the player score
                        onConsume = function(player, object)
                            gSounds['pickup']:play()
                            player.score = player.score + 500
                            keyCollected = true
                        end
                })
            end

            --spawn the locked box
            if x == lockBoxPosition then
                table.insert(objects,
                --locked box
                GameObject{
                    texture = 'key-lock',
                    x = (x-1) * TILE_SIZE,
                    Y = (blockHeight - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                    width = 16,
                    height = 16,

                    --make it a random variant
                    frame = keyColor + 4,
                    collidable = true,
                    hit = false,
                    solid = true,
                    lockedBox = false,

                    --collision function
                        onCollide = function(obj)
                            if not obj.hit then
                                if keyCollected then
                                    gSounds['pickup']:play()
                                    obj.hit = true
                                    --spawn flag post
                                    local flagpost = GameObject {
                                        texture = 'flagposts',
                                        x = obj.x + 4,
                                        y = (blockHeight - 4) * TILE_SIZE,
                                        width = 8,
                                        height = 48,
                                        frame = 1,
                                        collidable = true,
                                        consumable = true,
                                        solid = false,

                                        onConsume = function(player, object)
                                            gSounds['pickup']:play()
                                            player.score = player.score + 1000

                                            --end of the level
                                            gStateMachine:change('play', {score = player.score, lastLevelWidth = width})
                                        end
                                    }
                                    --spawn flag
                                    local flag = GameObject {
                                        texture = 'flags',
                                        x = obj.x + 6,
                                        y = (blockHeight - 2) * TILE_SIZE,
                                        width = 16,
                                        height = 10,
                                        frame = 1,
                                        collidable = true,
                                        consumable = true,
                                        solid = false,

                                        onConsume = function(player, object)
                                            gSounds['pickup']:play()
                                            player.score = player.score + 1000

                                            --end of the level
                                            gStateMachine:change('play', {score = player.score, lastLevelWidth = width})
                                        end
                                    }

                                    --raise the flag
                                    Timer.tween(2.0, {
                                        [flag] = {y = ((blockHeight - 4) * TILE_SIZE) + 4}
                                    })
                                    gSounds['powerup-reveal']:play()
                                    table.insert(objects, flagpost)
                                    table.insert(objects, flag)
                                end
                            end
                            gSounds['empty-block']:play()
                        end
                }
            )
            end

            -- chance to spawn a block
            if math.random(10) == 1 then
                table.insert(objects,

                    -- jump block
                    GameObject {
                        texture = 'jump-blocks',
                        x = (x - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                        y = (blockHeight - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                        width = 16,
                        height = 16,

                        -- make it a random variant
                        frame = math.random(#JUMP_BLOCKS),
                        collidable = true,
                        hit = false,
                        solid = true,

                        -- collision function takes itself
                        onCollide = function(obj)

                            -- spawn a gem if we haven't already hit the block
                            if not obj.hit then

                                -- chance to spawn gem, not guaranteed
                                if math.random(5) == 1 then

                                    -- maintain reference so we can set it to nil
                                    local gem = GameObject {
                                        texture = 'gems',
                                        x = (x - 1) * TILE_SIZE,
                                        y = (blockHeight - 1) * TILE_SIZE - 4,
                                        width = 16,
                                        height = 16,
                                        frame = math.random(#GEMS),
                                        collidable = true,
                                        consumable = true,
                                        solid = false,

                                        -- gem has its own function to add to the player's score
                                        onConsume = function(player, object)
                                            gSounds['pickup']:play()
                                            player.score = player.score + 100
                                        end
                                    }
                                    
                                    -- make the gem move up from the block and play a sound
                                    Timer.tween(0.1, {
                                        [gem] = {y = (blockHeight - 2) * TILE_SIZE}
                                    })
                                    gSounds['powerup-reveal']:play()

                                    table.insert(objects, gem)
                                end

                                obj.hit = true
                            end

                            gSounds['empty-block']:play()
                        end
                    }
                )
            end
        end
    end

    local map = TileMap(width, height)
    map.tiles = tiles
    
    return GameLevel(entities, objects, map)
end
```

and here is GameObject

```
    GameObject = Class{}

function GameObject:init(def)
    self.x = def.x
    self.y = def.y
    self.texture = def.texture
    self.width = def.width
    self.height = def.height
    self.frame = def.frame
    self.solid = def.solid
    self.collidable = def.collidable
    self.consumable = def.consumable
    self.onCollide = def.onCollide
    self.onConsume = def.onConsume
    self.hit = def.hit
end

function GameObject:collides(target)
    return not (target.x > self.x + self.width or self.x > target.x + target.width or
            target.y > self.y + self.height or self.y > target.y + target.height)
end

function GameObject:update(dt)

end

function GameObject:render()
    love.graphics.draw(gTextures[self.texture], gFrames[self.texture][self.frame], self.x, self.y)
end
```

the issue is supossedly in line 28 of GameObject

Comment: you probably didn't provide all code as the line number does not contain any arrithmetic operations. you're assinging a value to `Y` instead of `y` in this line: `Y = (blockHeight - 1) * TILE_SIZE,` of your code. that probably causes problems when you later want to do something with `y`

Comment: it was a typo! silly me hahaha thank you much